How to redirect a user to AppStore with query params you want to access after installing the app?
So essentially, what I want to achieve is to route the user to AppStore/PlayStore via the itunes/playstore links with some information appended to the url and then gain access to the query params in that url after the user has installed the app.
Example: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/${appName}/${appID}?userID=${userID}&amount=${amount}
And still have access to userID and amount when the app is launched.

What you want is not supported, at least on Android.

@CommonsWare are you aware of any other alternative way (that's not query params) to make this possible? Passing data from clicking the link to the user running the app.

For an ordinary Android app, there is no requirement for the user to launch your app immediately after installing it from the store. They could do so seconds to centuries later. Those query parameters may not be relevant at that point. What you seek does seem to be possible for a Google Play Instant app, where the link directly installs and launches a stripped-down initial module of your app experience.
